# Reach of manifold vs. $C^k$-manifold

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, computational-geometry

The *reach* $\tau_M$ of a manifold $M$ is the largest number such that any point at distance less than $\tau_M$ from $M$ has a unique nearest point on $M$.
This concept seems quite related to the *[local feature size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_feature_size)* introduced in computational geometry, but I haven't seen the two compared.
Two questions:

> ***Q1***. Is the reach identical (under appropriate assumptions) to the local feature size?
>
> ***Q2***. What is the relationship (if any) between a positive reach $\tau > 0$ 
>   of a manifold $M$ and its [$C^k$ smoothness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Definition)?
>   If $M$'s reach is $\tau > 0$, does that
>   imply anything about $k$? If $M$ is $C^k$-differentiable, does that imply
>   anything about $\tau$?

---

[image]

         

<sup>Image from [Hunting for Manifolds](https://normaldeviate.wordpress.com/2012/09/08/hunting-for-manifolds/), Larry Wasserman.</sup>

---

I think the answer to ***Q1*** is *Yes*, and to ***Q2*** is *None*. But I await responses from those who are more familiar with these concepts.

Comment: Positive reach implies that the submanifold is $C^{1,1}$; that is, 1-st derivatives is Lipschitz. The Lipschitz constant fro derivative gives a positive bound on reach locally, but might fail to give right global bound if the submanifold wiggles and comes back close to it self.

Comment: And in fact for hypersurfaces positive reach is equivalent to $C^{1,1}$, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.4179.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek; Thanks for the reference: Scholtes, Sebastian. "On hypersurfaces of positive reach, alternating Steiner formulae and Hadwiger's Problem."

Comment: The differentiability is intrinsic property of manifold whereas its reach depends on its embedding. You can construct infinitely smooth embeded submanifolds of positive reach for any $\tau > 0$. Just take a unit circle and pull point $[-1,0]$ towards $[0,1]$.